# Dataset on bilateral trade in services between India and other nations

Tags: data-request, india, trade

I am looking for a dataset on bilateral trade in services between India's top 10 trading parterns and India for the past 10 years. I have looked at the OECD STAN database, but that seems to only have manufacturing data. I tried to use the UN Comtrade database, but the generated results kept telling me that either there was no data, or that the query was too complex. The WTO database does not provide data on bilateral flows, so that does not suit my purposes.

Does anyone know where I can find year by year data on bilateral trade-in-services flows between nations.